# 2D Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For college, we have a problem to solve regarding 2D arrays, however the nature of them has never been cover in class. I've scoured this site for answers(which might be evident in my code) but cannot get it to work, or even truly understand what is going on or why. The exact question is:

```
Write a program that utilises a 8x8 2-dimensional array.  
(a) Initialise the array elements via nested for loops as follows

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
...
...
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64

(b) Add some code that will display all array elements in an 8x8 HTML table.

(c) Use nested for loops for calculating the sum and the average of the
    values stored in the array.
    Let a function display these values on screen eg use alert().
```

---

### The code I have so far is :

```
x = matrix( 8 , 8, 0 ); // 8 lines, 8 cols filled with empty string

function matrix( rows, cols, defaultValue){

   var arr = [];

     // Creates all lines:
     for(var i=0; i < rows; i++){

     var add = 1 

    // Creates an empty line
     arr.push([]);

      // Adds cols to the empty line:
     arr[i].push( new Array(cols));

        for(var j=0; j < cols; j++){
        // Initializes:
            arr[i][j] = defaultValue + add;
         }
  var add = add + 1
 }
    return arr;
}

function displayInDiv() {
  var output_string_ = "" ;
  var lastElement = 64 ;


output_string_ = output_string_
                +'<table>'
                +'<tr>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="left">ARRAY INDEX</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_1</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_2</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_3</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_4</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_5</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_6</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_7</th>'
                +'<th width="11%" align="right"> array_8</th>'
                +'</tr>'
                ;

for ( var i = 1 ; i < 9 ; i++ ) { 

    for ( var j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++ ) {

    output_string_ = output_string_
                    +'<tr id="table_row_'
                    + i
                    +'">'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="left">'
                    +'['
                    + i
                    +']'
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'<td width="11%" align="right">'
                    + Array[i][j]
                    +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>'
                    ;
}

    output_string_ = output_string_
                +'<table>'
                ;


var output_section_ = document.getElementById("list_");
output_section_.innerHTML = output_string_ ; 

}
}
```

---

Sorry for the huge text dump, but i'm completely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the exact code you're looking for is this

```
var outer = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var inner = new Array
  for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    inner[j] = (i * 8) + j + 1;
  }
  outer[i] = inner;
}

console.log(outer);
```

A 2D array is just an array of arrays, here I labelled them inner and outer.

There are 8 inner arrays of length 8, giving you 64 total entries. The value of each entry is 8 * the outer index (which starts at 0), plus the inner index plus 1 (because it also starts at 0).

This should give you enough information to answer parts `b` and `c` yourself, but feel free to comment below if you'd like further help. :)

Comment: This is perfect! Enough information for me to solve where I had gone wrong, and still leave enough for me to do so i can't claim it wasn't at least some of my own work. 

Sorry I didn't get back to this sooner, internet died at college minutes after posting this question, but managed to finish it at home. Thanks again. =D

Answer (score 2):

answer for (a)

```
var arr = [];
var value = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  var tempArr = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    tempArr.push(++value);
  }
  arr.push(tempArr);
}

//`arr` has values initialized with 1 - 64
```

---

answer for (b)

```
   var table = "<table>";

   for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      table += "<tr>";
      for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        table += "<td>" + arr[i][j] + "</td>";
      }
      table += "</tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";

//assume you have an element with id="tbl" in DOM
document.getElementById("tbl").innerHtml = table;
```

answer for (c)

```
 var sum = 0 , avg = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){          
      for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        sum += arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  avg = sum / 64;

 alert("sum: " + sum + " Average: " + avg);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create array you can initialize each of the element with another array.

```
var myarray=new Array(8)

for (i=0; i <8; i++)
    myarray[i]=new Array(8)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/o5nktuhj/1/) for this, with comments.

HTML

```
<button onclick="showCalculations();">Show Calculations!</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
//Create the 2-d array
var rows = 8; //Number of rows
var columns = 8; //Number of columns
var list = []; //Array where we will put the data
var index = 0; //Keeps track of which index we're at

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  var rowList = []; //Create sub-array
  list.push(rowList); //Add the sub-array to our top-level array
  for(var y = 0; y < columns; y++){
    index++; //Increment the index
    rowList.push(index); //Add the index to the current sub-array
  }
}

//Create the Table as HTML string
var table = "<table>"; //Start HTML for table
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  var row = list[i];
  table += "<tr>"; //Start HTML for row
  for(var y = 0; y < row.length; y++){
    var column = row[y];
    table += "<td>" + column + "</td>"; //Table cell with content
  }
  table += "</tr>"; //End HTML for row
}
table += "</table>"; //End HTML for table

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = table; //Find element with id container and set HTML to table

//Calculations
var sum = 0; //Keeps track of the sum
var numberOfNumbers = 0; //Keeps track of how many numbers has been summed

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  var row = list[i];
  for(var y = 0; y < row.length; y++){
    var column = row[y];
    sum += column; //Add to sum
    numberOfNumbers++; //Increment amount of numbers
  }
}

var avarage = sum / numberOfNumbers; //Calculate avarage

//Function to alert the values
function showCalculations(){
  alert("Sum: " + sum + "\nAvarage: " + avarage)
}
```

Note that the creation of the Table and the calculations can be done in the same `for-loop`. (Acctually all can be, but then we're not making use of the Array we create).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num;
var arr = [];

// This for loop populates the array
for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = i * 8 + j + 1;
  }
}

//  This function displays the populated array
function displayArr(arr) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var append = "<table>";

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    append += "<tr>";

    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      num = i * 8 + j + 1;
      append += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
    }

    append += "</tr>";
  }
  
  container.innerHTML = append;
}

//  Alerts the sum of all numbers in the 2d array
function getSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
      sum += i * 8 + j + 1;
    }

  }
  return sum;
}


// Alerts the average of all numbers in the 2d array
function getAvg() {
  var totalNumbers = 0;
  var avg = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
      totalNumbers++;
    }

  }
  return getSum() / totalNumbers;
}


alert(getAvg());
alert(getSum());
displayArr(arr);
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
```

**EDIT* Added the average and sum functions**

Answer (score 0):

I correct your code. Html:

```
<button onclick='run()'>Show</button>
<div id='list_'></div>
```

And js:

```
function run() {
  x = matrix( 8 , 8, 0 ); 
  alert(x);
  displayInDiv(x);
}
function matrix( rows, cols, defaultValue){
    var arr = [];
    var number = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        arr.push([]);
        arr[i].push( new Array(cols));
        for(var j=0; j < cols; j++){
            arr[i][j] = number;
            number++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function displayInDiv() {
    var output_string_ = "" ;
    var lastElement = 64 ;
    var output_string_ = '<table>'
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ) { 
        output_string_ += "<tr id='table_row_" + i + "'>";
        for ( var j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ ) {
            output_string_ += '<td width="11%" align="left">' + x[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
        output_string_ += '</tr>';
    }
    output_string_ += '</table>';

    var output_section_ = document.getElementById("list_");
    output_section_.innerHTML = output_string_ ; 
}
```