# 2d Tilemap with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Creating a little program with javascript and html and I want to draw up a 9x5 grid of tiles (all the same image). I also want to get the x and y coordinates (its position in the grid) of a tile when the user clicks it.

I'm still new to Javascript so struggling a bit and nothing I found online worked for me, most examples were for players drawing up tilemaps for 2d games that required extra functionality or more tile images.

```
var map = {
    cols: 9,
    rows: 5,
    tiles: [
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    ]
}
```

Above is what I'm thinking it would look like, just a simple array for a map. But I still need to actually draw it on the page and get the x and y coordinates when clicked on.

Comment: If you are new to JS, I suggest you to use a HTML table to draw your grid.

Comment: you can use a library like phaser https://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/tilemaps or if you want to implement it yourself you can use div or 2D canvas https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp.

Comment: Go through all examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091391/2d-arrays-in-javascript/34091642 Hopefully it will give enough of a hint.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll check it all out.